# How to create a unique product page for an eCommerce website?

Tags: php, mysql, database, loops, product

I have a database set up with a couple of products on it.

I'm just struggling with the product page, you know the page that you are directed to when you click on a particular product - for the details, description  and add to cart button etc. How would I create one of these? Surely not with an

```
<a href="product"></a>
```

on every single product, right?

I currently have a while loop that loops through the database to display all of the products. So if I use the

```
<a href="product"></a>
```

it will just take me to the same product page every time.

Here is the loop of the database:

```
 <?php include 'connect.php';
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE featured = 1";
 $featured = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 ?>

<?php while ($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)): ?>
    <div class="products">
       <a href="#"><img src="<?= $product['image'];?>" height="300" 
       width="275"></a>
       <a href="#"> <p><?=$product['title'];?></p></a><br>
         <p>Usual Price: £<s><?= $product['list_price'];?></s></p>
         <p>Sale Price: £<?= $product['price'];?></p>
    </div>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

How would I create a unique product page for each product?

Comment: Unless you're prepared for a whole world of hurt, don't write your own e-commerce software. This goes doubly if you're **handling real money**. Use an existing package and adapt or extend it to your needs. [Magento](https://www.magento.com) to pick but one example, is far better than what any one person can put together on their own.

Comment: hey man thanks for the advice. It's just that i have enrolled onto a college course (UK) starting in September and was told by the tutor that it would be an assignment to build an eCommerce site. I don't know the extent of what she meant but i'm trying to learn all that i can.

Comment: Even if you're compelled to roll your own because it's an academic project with that as a goal, take some time to study how packages like Magento handle this. Also examine the parameters of your assignment carefully. If you can use a framework like [Laravel](https://laravel.com) or [Fat Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/home) as a foundation you'll get a lot more done without fussing around with fundamentals that aren't part of your work scope.

Comment: The way to handle this is with a routing layer and those are typically coupled to a [Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller) driven back-end. Most frameworks give you something like this to start with, but if you were *really* constrained, you could write your own if you knew how one worked. Learn from good examples!

Comment: Thanks so much for the great advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you create a unique SKU for each item number (put this sku in the database) and then create another page.   Let's say the new page is called item.php

So in your category listing page you can list the link like this:

```
<a href="item.php?sku=<?php echo $product['sku']; ?>"> </a>
```

and your next step would be to figure out how to pull in the individual product's information into item.php based on the sku in the url.

Comment: honestly kyle, I was looking EVERYWHERE on the internet for some info on this. THANKYOU! It worked like a charm.

Comment: Thank you for this even I was searching for this everywhere!